# PI Zero SPI info needed for Python

Tags: python, spi

I'm trying to program the SPI in Python but the documentation is terrible. [SPI Docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md)

I found some sites that show how to get started but I need to know how to change modes, set clock polarity, and set clock idle state.  I can't find anything on the internet that shows how to do this in Python.  One site showed code for mode = 0, but what is mode 0?

Here is the code I have for setting it up.

```
# We only have SPI bus 0 available to us on the Pi
bus = 0
#Device is the chip select pin. Set to 0 or 1, depending on the connections
device = 0 #worked on 0 and 1
# Enable SPI
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
# Open a connection to a specific bus and device (chip select pin)
spi.open(bus, device)
# Set SPI speed and mode
spi.max_speed_hz = 500000
spi.mode = 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to connect using spi?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link is to the UART.

See https://pypi.org/project/spidev/ for the available spidev module documentation.

As for the meaning of mode perhaps look at a SPI wiki.